# CTRL J on my mirrored object is creating a duplicate

Tags: mirror

For some reason, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on my model selecting first the helmet (which is mirrored) and then the rest of the other parts of my model (which some of them are mirrored too), the result is my model being together yes, but also having a duplicate inside of it as well as the images below show. The first is before <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>, the second is the result.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the mirror modifiers on your objects might be shifting due to the main object your joining having a different origin point causing some deviations, perhaps try applying all the modifiers first before joining

Comment: so should i change the origin points in my objects or i should apply the mirror modifier in all of the objects? if so, how could i do it? i don't think applying the mirror modifier to objects that don't have it to be the solution, i mean, even objects that do have the mirror modifier are being duplicated.

Comment: Your mirror modifier objects get duplicated even if they get applied by themselves? Might need to check out the blend file to get a better idea of whats going. Could you add an image of an example objects modifiers?

Comment: If the object that you are joining all the other objects **to** has a modifier on it, all the other joined objects will inherit that modifier.  And please delete the duplicate question you asked first!

Comment: sorry if i'm violating some rule of blender forum, but why is that i need to delete the duplicate question? it's literally the problem i'm having, i need people to answer it because it's just the thing i need help solving.

Comment: Because some people might see the other question first and add a comment or answer to that while there's already an answer to this one. So you'll get fragmentation of comments and answers to an identical question.

Comment: Hello please don't ask twice the same question  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I now know finally how i can solve this issue, and it's something that many people have already told me but i never knew or understood what was being told to me. Basically, all that it's needed to do is apply the mirror modifier on the object that it has to be mirrored, by going to the object that has the mirror modifier, and there will be an arrow close to an X on the tab of the mirror modifier applied. Then click on the arrow, click on "apply". And then, when you use the mirrored object as starting point when you want to join all the meshes together, the other objects will not encounter any problem. I would recommend applying the mirror modifier in all objects that do have it before joining meshes, just in case ;)

Comment: You can just hover the mouse over the modifier on the panel and hit Ctrl-A to apply it. In fact, if you join all the objects to one which has **no** modifier on it the modifiers which were on the other objects that you're joining to it will be removed without being applied.